# Get the correct port number from LiveServerTestCase in Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, selenium

When trying to test the admin login using the following code, I found the self.live_server_url returns something like `http://localhost:39346`, where the port number is different on each running.

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver

class AdminLoginTests(LiveServerTestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()
    super(AdminLoginTests, self).setUp()

def tearDown(self):
    self.selenium.quit()
    super(AdminLoginTests, self).tearDown()

def test_admin_login(self):
    # ...
    print('url: %s' %self.live_server_url)
```

How do I get the correct port number `8000` of the running server? Suppose I run the server through `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LiveServerTestCase](https://github.com/django/django/blob/cb7860ccedb199cb221c9e084b5104978b246356/django/test/testcases.py#L1251) spawns a new instance with that port on purpose. That way you can test a production environment without having to shutdown the production server (which by default runs on 8000).

However if you want to change the port that the debug is running on you can initialize to a different port number.

```
class TempTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TempTest, self).__init__()
        self.port = 8910

    def setUp(self)
        # ....
```

Comment: Thanks. This somehow generates an error: TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. Let's see if I can figure it out.

Comment: It is just fine to use the ports assigned by the system. Thanks!

Comment: @Luke i have the same problem... how did you use the system assigned port and make it work? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me under Django version 1.11.26

```
class TempTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    port = 8888
    host = "0.0.0.0" # If you want your test server to be public
```